# Azure Blob Files with Different Sets of Columns

Tags: azure, hive

In an Azure Blob container there are files with different sets of columns.

E.g. 
File1: Col1, Col2, Col3
File2: Col1, Col3
File3: Col2, Col3

How can I query these files all at the same time?

It seems with PolyBase this is not possible as files need to have the same set of columns.

Is it possible to use Hive by doing some kind of mapping of columns?

Thanks

Mehmet

Comment: We're you able to find a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using Hadoop and Hive, you would have to write a lot of custom code to dynamically calculate the columns each time you queried the "table". Your performance would take a large hit and the manageability of such a code base would be a nightmare. The correct way to do this is to move each set of files so that they are in there own "folder" within blob storage. This will allow Polybase/Hadoop to manage them natively.

That being said, you could benefit from Hadoop's distributed architecture to reorganize the files for you.

Answer (score -1):

Columns is more related to Table in Azure Storage. This isn't related to a blob. Blob storage is for raw/unstructured file